# Find row wise max from two different columns with update function

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can anyone help me with UPDATE with max?

TABLE-A

```
EMP SALARY  BONUS
A   100     110
B   50      80
C   30      20
D   80      50
E   30      40
```

I want Answer like

TABLE-A

```
EMP SALARY  BONUS   MAX
A   100      110    110
B   50        80    80
C   30        20    30
D   80        50    80
E   30        40    40
```

Comment: sqlserver <> mysql. Choose one tag please :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GREATEST`(MySQL):

```
UPDATE tableA
SET `max` = GREATEST(Salary, Bonus);
```

I would suggest adding computed column to avoid updating in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA(Emp INT, Salary INT, BONUS INT,
                    `max` INT AS (GREATEST(Salary, Bonus)));
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/IKBQG52118)**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server you could use a `CASE STATEMENT`

```
select
   EMP,
   SALARY,
   BONUS,
   [Max] = case when Salary > Bonus then Salary else Bonus end
from
   TABLE-A
```

Or on the update...

```
UPDATE TABLE-A
SET [Max] = case when Salary > Bonus then Salary else Bonus end
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012+:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET [MAX] = IIF (SALARY > BONUS, SALARY, BONUS);
```